# Nvidia GEforce GTX installed on Ubuntu 20.04 but no processes running

Tags: gpu, nvidia-geforce

I installed all the possible drivers: 435, 440, 450… none of them seems to work. The system recognizes the GPU but no process is running on it. It is not a hardware problem because the GPU works fine in windows… This issue is really killing me… could you please provide help? Thanks in advance

```
nvidia-smi
Sun Aug 30 20:38:43 2020
±----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.95.01 Driver Version: 440.95.01 CUDA Version: 10.2 |
|-------------------------------±---------------------±---------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0 GeForce GTX 166… Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off | N/A |
| N/A 50C P0 8W / N/A | 0MiB / 5944MiB | 0% Default |
±------------------------------±---------------------±---------------------+

±----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: GPU Memory |
| GPU PID Type Process name Usage |
|=============================================================================|
| No running processes found |
±----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Run `prime-select query` to check which GPU is your PC using. To set Nvidia as the primary GPU, run `sudo prime-select nvidia`

Comment: I already tried that, it is using nvidia from the beginning "the nvidia profile is already set"

Answer (score -1):

I believe this driver is not suitable you must use other drivers from the additional drivers menu or find a suitable one from the nvidia website. I had the same issue, with nvidia 460. The GPU was being recognized however not utilized. After starting using 418, although it is not showing the processes running the GPU (it says 'not supported') I can see the GPU memory being utilized when I run i.e. Firefox

Comment: Please don't recommend "one from the nvidia website". All reuired drivers are already in the Ubuntu repository and in the rare cases a newer version is required for a brand new card there's a PPA for that.

Comment: I didn't mean "download from the Nvidia Website". You can download their recommended driver version from ppa that's what I did and it's working fine.